# Magento 2 How to sort admin column in desc order?

Tags: magento2, grid, sorting

I have a custom grid, I am trying to sort it in desc order
**What I did**

**Try 1**:- In my Grid Collection:

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
        $orderUpdate = $this->getTable('xyztable');
        $this->getSelect()->order('main_table.order_id', 'desc');
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

**Try 2**:- In uicomponent file:

```
<column name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

[image: here]

> **Output**: It sort like: 1, 10, 12, 2, 3, 4, 41, 42, 5
>
> **Expected Result**: 42, 41, 12, 10, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

I had spend couple of hours in this but didn't find any solution. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, After speding couple of hours I checked the column `order_id` is `varchar` type because of which sorting result was not accurate. I make it `int(10)` and issue solved.

Comment: did you change any xml code so that it worked or you just changed your order_id column datatype to int(10). Please guide me actually i am facing similar issue here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316094/custom-column-sortingdesc-and-asc-not-working-in-custom-grid-magento-2-3-5.